# AppleScript : Remove class if

Tags: applescript, safari, javascript

How can I remove each class on Safari, only for specific text ?

I know this script bellow would remove every class named  :

> sortable itemDescription

```
tell application "Safari Technology Preview" to ¬
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"sortable itemDescription\\\"]\").forEach(el => el.remove());" in current tab of window 1
```

But can I add an if statement to only remove the class if the text is, in this exemple :

> "(unwanted") :

```
<td class="sortable itemDescription">

                                    (unwanted)

                            </td>
```

Comment: While AppleScript and JavaScript for Automation is on-topic, questions about JavaScript in general and especially about web development should be asked on Stack Overflow. You can remove the AppleScript wrapper and focus on the JavaScript in this question.

Comment: In the consol I have the error "SyntaxError: Invalid escape in identifier: '\'" , it's just suppose to click a hidden link on a specific webpage, which work fine when I use the AppleScript script.

Comment: Because backslashes have been used to escape the quotes to nest the JavaScript within the AppleScript. Remove one layer of escaping of the backslashes before running the JavaScript string as JavaScript in the console.

Comment: Yes, now you've removed *all* the escaping instead of just one layer. You need to escape the quotes around `\"advanced-search\"` to prevent the quotes around the selector `"[…]"` from being closed too soon.

Comment: @Kevin Would you mind if we use this and some other questions you've asked to discuss on [meta] when we want to close something as off topic here when it's about doing something using Apple automation tools?

Comment: Since we're seeing this as a pure JS question where you're only embedding a JS question in AppleScript - let's get this to SO. Please flag me in comments if it gets closed on SO as off topic - I'd like to get this clarified if it's really on topic here.